# Notification actions not calling broadcast receiver Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to add 2 actions my FCM notifications

1. Mark Important
2. Mark Read

I have created a Broadcast receiver, but the `OnReceive` of the Broadcast receiver is not getting called.

This is the code where I create a notification with the 2 actions:

```
   [Service, IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class FCMListenerService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        private string Tag = "FCM_Listener_Service";

        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            var data = message.Data;

            var notification = new FCMNotificationDTO(data);

            SendNotification(notification);
        }

        private void SendNotification(FCMNotificationDTO notification)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BaseDrawActivity));

            intent.PutExtra("NotificationId", notification.NotificationId);


            var openActivityIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);

            //important intent
            Intent importantIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.myapp.NotificationActionHandler");
            importantIntent.SetAction(NotificationActionHandler.MARK_IMPORTANT);
            PendingIntent intentImportant = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, importantIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            //read intent
            Intent readIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.myapp.NotificationActionHandler");
            readIntent.SetAction(NotificationActionHandler.MARK_READ);
            PendingIntent intentRead = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, readIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);


            var notificationBuilder =
                             new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                 // .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                                 .SetContentTitle(notification.AlertName)
                                 .SetContentText(notification.Reference)
                                 .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                 .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
                                 .SetContentIntent(openActivityIntent) // When the notification is clicked open the notification activity
                                 .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_alert_circle_outline, GetText(Resource.String.important), intentImportant)
                                 .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_eye_outline, GetText(Resource.String.mark_read), intentRead)
                                 ;

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(notification.NotificationId, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
```

My BroadCast Receiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Name = "com.myapp.myapp.NotificationActionHandler")]
public class NotificationActionHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static string MARK_READ = "MARK_READ";
    public static string MARK_IMPORTANT = "MARK_IMPORTANT";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var action = intent.Action;

        switch (action)
        {
            case "MARK_IMPORTANT":
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Mark important notification", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;

            case "MARK_READ":
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Mark read notification", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

After building the app the Manifest contains the Broad cast receiver details

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.myapp.myapp.NotificationActionHandler" />
```

Comment: try calling new Intent(this, NotificationActionHandler.class) instead.

Comment: @Linxy it worked - thanks